# Cocos2dx - android apk crashes on start

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to run cocos2dx sample project (the one created with create-android-project script) on Android device or emulator.

However the application crashes on start with the following errors:

> 10-16 10:50:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(379): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-16
>   10:50:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(379): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.geckolab/com.geckolab.mahjong}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.geckolab.mahjong in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.geckolab-1.apk] 10-16
>   10:50:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
>   10-16 10:50:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(379):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   10-16 10:50:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(379):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 10-16
>   10:50:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   10-16 10:50:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(379):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-16
>   10:50:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 10-16 10:50:02.249:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(379):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 10-16
>   10:50:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-16
>   10:50:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 10-16 10:50:02.249:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(379):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   10-16 10:50:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(379):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 10-16
>   10:50:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-16 10:50:02.249:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(379): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.geckolab.mahjong in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.geckolab-1.apk] 10-16
>   10:50:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
>   10-16 10:50:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(379):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573) 10-16
>   10:50:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532) 10-16
>   10:50:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
>   10-16 10:50:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(379):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
>   10-16 10:50:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(379):    ... 11 more

Any idea what is going wrong? The build_native.sh script seems to work fine, I resolved some Eclipse errors by changing compiler complience level to 1.6 and adding libcocos2dx.jar to my project's build path.

Cheers,
Marcin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must remember to instantiate the activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

EDIT : Check your project properties and make sure that all jars or libraries of crocos2d are checked for order and export.

Comment: I know - the manifest file generated automatically and it already contains the activity defined as follows:         <activity android:name=".mahjong"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  
                  android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Have you tried clearing your project and restarting Eclipse? Also could you edit your original question and paste everything you have in `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: Check your project properties and make sure that all jars or libraries of crocos2d are checked for order and export.

Comment: It works! The problem was with not checked cocos2dxlib.jar under the Order and Export tab. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I meet the same problem. And it works after I check cocos2dslib.jar under Order and Export tab. That helps me a lot. Haha. Thank you very much.

Comment: It also worked for me in version 3.4 and Eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem. 
I have everything configured. No jar file is added to build path in my case because I have a cocos2dx library added to the project which contains libscocos2dx.jar

Although I have a so file which normally is not required to be added to the build path but I have added that as well just to check it works or not and unfortunately it didnt

Comment: further more let me know which activity you are talking about, the one I just created or the one which is extended from cocos2dxActvity

Answer (score 0):

Solution: RESTART YOUR IDE! Then remove project errors (probably connected with libcocos2dx that it can't find).